# How to edit datagridview row and re-insert row index back to datagridview after editing

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to edit and update a single row in datagridview using two forms. selecting the desired row to edit from datagridview in Form2, and displaying the data in textboxes on Form3 is not the issue. My issue is sending the changed data from the textboxes on Form3 back to Form2.

I have tried declaring a public variable for the selected row index in the datagridview_cellClickevent on form2, and calling upon that variable in form3 to return the data, yet i cannot refer to the variable in form3.

Public Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

```
    'This is the variable declared to represent the selected row in datagridview1 on form2
    Dim index As Decimal = e.RowIndex
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)
```

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 Handles ButtonUpdate.Click
        'This is form3 where index is in error after 
trying to pull from public form2

```
    Dim Update_Row As DataGridViewRow
    Update_Row = Form2.DataGridView1.Rows(Index)
    Update_Row.Cells(1).Value = TBLastNameEdit.Text
    Update_Row.Cells(2).Value = TBFirstNameEdit.Text
    Update_Row.Cells(3).Value = CBGenderEdit.Text
```

I expect the declaration of "index" to show on form3 without error however and error occurs where "index" is not accessible because it is "friend". if there is anyway to accomplish this task please let me know, or, if you have any other suggestions on returning the updated data to the datagridview please let me know. thank you for your time.

- for some reason "Index" is not shown in error on my code snipet here, however it does show in error "inaccessible because "index" is friend" on visual studio

Comment: I'ld use a BindingSource to bind the DataSource (DataTable or other) to the DataGridView.DataSource. Pass the BindingSource to the other Form (via constructor, public property/method). Use the BindingSource to add a Binding to each of the controls that need to update the data. Add a handler to the `Parse` event of the Binding. When it's raised (you change the value of the bound property of a control), call `[BindingSource].CurrencyManager.Refresh()`. You can then see the DataGridView in the first Form change its values in real time.

Comment: I mean, even if you show the second Form as Modal (i.e., `Form3.ShowDialog()`)

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your input. I am still pretty new to programming so i am looking more in depth to working with the parse event. I ended up using a combination of the code answer below and actually reversing my datagrideviewselectedrow-to-textbox code using the bindingsource that i had previously placed on the form. It worked like a charm. Thank you for your input as it really helped lead to success in the end. I appreciate your time and effort in helping me resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your exact need, I really just finished it by now , Just follow those instructions carefully in the attached text file for this solution on this [link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/4y1xr3z2ad3y6un/DGVRowFin.txt/file)

I hope this is useful for you all ^_^

Kindly, find the project source on this [link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/7h286au7rn956nt/DGVRowTransfer.rar/file)

[image]

Comment: This is great work thank you, i appreciate your time and effort sincerely.

Comment: I am happy to hear that ... ^_^